# Nested Polymer Custom Components Data Binding

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I cannot get data to round trip from a child component to the parent component and back to a child component.

I have made a simple nested component testbed. Here is the child:

```dart
<link rel="import" href="../packages/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="child-comp" attributes="x y">
  <template>
    <input type='text' value='{{x}}'/>
    <p>-x={{x}}-</p>
    <p>list:
      <template repeat='{{y}}'>-{{ }}-</template>
    </p>
  </template>

  <script type='application/dart'>
    import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

    @CustomTag('child-comp')
    class ChildComp extends PolymerElement {
      @observable var x;
      @observable var y;

      ChildComp.created() : super.created();
      }
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

It takes a text input (x) and echoes it out (the p immediately after the input). It also send x back to the parent control where it is added to a list (y) that should then be iterated through in the child.

Here is the parent component:

```dart
<link rel="import" href="../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../components/child_comp.html">

<polymer-element name="top-comp">
  <template>
    <child-comp x='{{s}}' y='{{t}}'></child-comp>
  </template>

  <script type='application/dart'>
    import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

    @CustomTag('top-comp')
    class TopComp extends PolymerElement {
      @observable String        s = '1234';
      @observable List<String>  t = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

      TopComp.created() : super.created();

      sChanged(oldVal, newVal) {
        t.add(newVal);
        }
      }

  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

From the child to the parent works and the change is correctly added to the List. But the List does not seem to get to the child - the DOM is never updated.

I have tried every possible combination of the decorators, but perhaps the answer is in a variant of the bind= syntax..

A side note: is there authoritative updated documentation on the decorators? Searching turns up a bunch of references of varying antiquity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need to make sure that not only is your `List` observable, but also its elements. You can do so like this:

```dart
@observable List<String>  t = toObservable(['A', 'B', 'C']);
```

This way, changes to `t`'s elements (instead of just `t` itself) are "announced", and the DOM can update accordingly.

Comment: That worked! Much appreciated. Do you remember how you discovered this? Is there anything which lays out what happens when the decorator is applied?

Comment: Been a long time since I learned it. Not sure where from. But @observable causes the reference to the List to throw PropertyChanged events, and toObservable() takes a List or Map and does the same for the internal elements, so that changes to the elements that don't alter the List reference also fire PropertyChanged events. Essentially, that's it, anyway.